# How to change images in Div whenever someone clicks or hovers over the Menu which has 4-5 hyperlinks ( Menu items ) using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I can think of various solutions , like creating 3 different HTML documents each having different image and linking these HTML files to the Menu in which I want to change the image .

I know it is possible by jquery , I just need some help in understand so that I can achieve this .

Comment: Post a link to the code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you're looking for something like this (***See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fWpJz/1/)***):

HTML

```
​<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" data-image-src="1.jpg">link 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-image-src="2.jpg">link 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-image-src="3.jpg">link 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-image-src="4.jpg">link 4</a>
  <a href="#" data-image-src="5.jpg">link 5</a>
</div>

​<div id="container">
  <img src="">
</div>​
```

JavaScript

```
​$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu a').hover(function () {
        $('#container img').attr('src', $(this).data('image-src'));
    });
});​
```

*In this code you place source of image which should be shown when you hover over the link in data attribute in the link. And when you hover over the link it calls callback in which current source of image changes.*

**UPDATED**

***See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fWpJz/1/)***

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check out the following:

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Just create a function to handle the image swapping, and then bind an event handler for the element to hover/click.

You can also achive this with CSS like .class:hover { background-image: .... }

Comment: I am checking the links . Thanks a lot for the help !